# Angular show Element only if it exceeds viewport - Fix ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to display a second paginator at the bottom of my table whenever the table exceeds the viewport. However, I always get an **ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError**. I have tried using the ChangeDetectorRef, a property with onResize with a HostListener, but I always seem to just get a different error. I hope someone can help me find the "Angular-way" to solve this problem.

This is my template:

```
...
<div #tableContainer class="table-container">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="messages" class="messages">
      [...]
    </table>
</div>

<mat-toolbar *ngIf="isOutOfViewport(tableContainer)" class="toolbar">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <app-manual-paginator class="paginator"
                          [length]="resultCount"
                          [(pageSize)]="pageSize"
                          [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 75, 100]"
                          [(pageIndex)]="page"
                          [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
                          (changePage)="changePage()">
    </app-manual-paginator>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
...
```

The Method inside the component that I call:

```
public isOutOfViewport(element: Element): boolean {
  const bounds = getViewportOutOfBounds(element);
  return bounds.top || bounds.bottom;
}
```

And the Utility Method used to find the bounds (got it from an online guide: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-check-if-any-part-of-an-element-is-out-of-the-viewport-with-vanilla-js/):

```
export function getViewportOutOfBounds(element: Element): Bounds {

    // Get element's bounds
    const bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Check if it's out of the viewport on each side
    const out: Bounds = {
    top: undefined,
    bottom: undefined,
    left: undefined,
    right: undefined,
    any: undefined,
    all: undefined
  };
    out.top = bounds.top < 0;
    out.left = bounds.left < 0;
    out.bottom = bounds.bottom > (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    out.right = bounds.right > (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);
    out.any = out.top || out.left || out.bottom || out.right;
    out.all = out.top && out.left && out.bottom && out.right;

    return out;
};
```

I have verified that the methods do in fact work on their own, but in this constelation I can't seem to get it working.